# React context provider not setting value on page load/refresh

Tags: reactjs

I have the following hook for Pusher and I use it to share one instance across the application.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";

const PusherContext = React.createContext<Pusher | undefined>(undefined);
export const usePusher = () => useContext(PusherContext)

export const PusherProvider: React.FC = (props) => {
    const pusherRef = useRef<Pusher>();

    useEffect(() => {
        pusherRef.current = new Pusher(PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
           cluster: 'eu'
        })

        return () => pusherRef.current?.disconnect()
    }, [pusherRef]);

    return (
        <PusherContext.Provider value={pusherRef.current}>
            {props.children}
        </PusherContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The problem is that the provider always has an `undefined` value on page refresh/load. But when I trigger a re-render the value is correctly set. I would like to have the instance without the need of re-rendering.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the next construction:

```
export const PusherProvider = (props) => {
  const pusher = useMemo(() => new Pusher(APP_PUSHER_KEY, { cluster: 'eu' }), [])

  useEffect(() => () => pusher.disconnect(), [pusher])

  return <PusherContext.Provider value={pusher}>{props.children}</PusherContext.Provider>
}
```

Comment: I assume this should work, but I've read that using refs for third-party libraries is the way to go?

Comment: I don't think using ref makes any more sacred sense here. Yes, it can be a little more productive, since the set function is not created. But, I think, this is not so important for such places, which can be called only once during the entire operation time of the application.

Comment: @Stephan882 I have replaced useState with useMemo.

Comment: Alright, I've got a few more questions. Why are you calling a function that calls another function? `() => () => pusher.disconnect()` Can't we do it `() => pusher.disconnect()`?. And  what if we use the provider more than once? Will we share one instance, or it will run `new Pusher` multiple times?

Comment: Yeah, I saw. You were 1 minute ahead

Comment: From the useEffect callback, we return a function with instructions to clear the effect. So it must be () => () => pusher.disconnect(). To use Pusher in more than one place you should put PusherContext in code so it is available for all its users.

Comment: Alright. I'll stick with your solution. I'd love to see what other people think. I really aprreciate it, thank you! By the way, I like your solution since it does not make me check every time for undefined after using `usePusher` inside a component!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by following way.
If you set State/const data inside "useEffect" will not work. as that will not run when page refresh but the state declaration those are outside the "useEffect" will run. Hence it will reset default values.

So I resolved by setting the state/const value outside of "useEffect" and done.

[image: Authentication Context - Demo code]